# Project dependencies in Android.mk

Tags: android, dependencies, android-source, android.mk

I want to build my app while flashing custom ROM on the device. I'm trying to find proper way to include project dependencies in the Android.mk. My dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {  
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
wearApp project(':wear')  
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'  
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'  
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'  
compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.2@aar'
```

How to put it into the makefile? As static libraries? Or maybe as extra packages? Waiting for your help!